# SWFObject Flash Player Script: Wode = Transparent?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, swfobject

I'm using the SWFObject script (http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject) to embedd a flash object into the following page: http://parramatta.pjgallaghers.com.au/_flashvr/test

The flash is from an external supplier and I don't have a whole lot of control over it apart from the embed script. For some reason once the Flash has finished loading the website's main menu drop down's stop appearing - if you hover over different menu options before and whilst the flash is loading you see it's normal drop down behaviour..

Does anyone know what could have caused this?
(This is an old website, please excuse the sloppy code..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your site in Mozilla Firefox 3.1 beta 3, Internet Explorer 8, and Google Chrome 2 beta, and the menus work. What I've noticed is that my CPU usage (Core 2 Duo) shot up to 80% once your flash has completed loading.

Your page source is quite hard to read, do you have a better indented one?

Comment: I've just checked it and see that the menu's do work but they are very delayed which I think leads me to my next question about your CPU usage shooting up 80%. I presume this ties in with the delayed menu drop downs? My CPU did the same thing.

Sorry about the code as I said, it's an old website.

Answer (score 1):

Use wmode opaque to get the stacking order working with your menus while minimizing CPU usage (wmode transparent should be avoided as much as possible due to known bugs and heavy resource hogging). Examples can be found [here](http://pipwerks.com/lab/swfobject/z-index/2.0/index.html)